# Ant Task: Copy all scripts used in HTML File to a directory and compress

Tags: javascript, ant, compression, copy, concatenation

I'm currently trying to create an ANT build.xml that should do the following:

Find all occurences of a <script src="foo.js"> tag in a HTML file. Take the src attribute of that script file and copy the corresponding js file to a temp directory. Then concatenate all the scripts in the directory so that there will be one big script. Finally compress the script (with YUI compressor). I havent got much experience in ANT builds, but this is how I came so far:

```
<target name="concat">
    <copy todir="${output.dir}/js/temp">
        <fileset dir="${src.dir}">
            <include name="if.html"/>
        </fileset>
        <filterchain>
            <linecontainsregexp>
                <regexp pattern="script.*src=&quot;(.*?)&quot;" />
            </linecontainsregexp>
            <tokenfilter>
                <replaceregex pattern=".*&lt;script.*src=&quot;(.*?)&quot;&gt;.*" replace="\1" />
            </tokenfilter>

        </filterchain>      
    </copy>

    <concat destfile="${output.dir}/js/application.js">
        <fileset dir="${output.dir}/js/temp" includes="*.js" />
    </concat>
</target>
```

Until now the buildscript will get all javascripts paths from the file if.html. I will create a file if.html in the folder "${output.dir}/js/temp" and put all the paths in there. But this is not what I want. I want all script files to be copied in the "${output.dir}/js/temp" so I can concat them in the next step.

Thanks for any help!

Regards

Comment: why you need to find all occurences of a <script> tag in the HTML file? why you don't just copy all the _js files_ found in the _js directory_ of your web application to _${output.dir}/js/temp_ then concatenating them?

Comment: Because not all files in my script directory are used in that HTML file. There are also some debug and test scripts. Because of that I only want to copy the scripts that are really used in that HTML file.

Comment: So why do you put all the js scripts inside a single folder? Why not put different kinds of js files in different folders?

Comment: Don't forget that the scripts also must be imported in a fixed order. E.g. jquery.js must be imported before other scripts. But if a script is named ascript.js it will come in fromt of jquery as the item is the script folder are sorted my name.

Answer (score 1):

So finally I got it working by using an ANT Plugin called "ant-contrib". 
This adds the possibility to use a for loop in ANT Scripts.

```
  <loadfile property="file" srcfile="${output.dir}/js/temp/if.html"/>
  <for param="line" list="${file}" delimiter="${line.separator}">
          <sequential>       
            <concat destfile="${output.dir}/js/application.js" append="true">
                 <fileset dir="${src.dir}" includes="@{line}" />
            </concat>
            <echo message="Adding js ${src.dir}/@{line}"/>
          </sequential>
  </for>
```

Now I can loop through the lines of the file (each line is a path to a js file) and append the filecontent to the main application.js.